# Call Asynctask from different class Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I got class calledA  and my async class is written as a inner class of A. I got another class called B(Activity). Now im in B class. what i want is to call asyncTask of A.

I'm much confused with this question & if anyone can give me a correct answer he'll be a life saver. Hope u guys help me. Thanks.

Comment: make separate(not in A or B) class of Asyntask and implement custom listeners.

Comment: You should maintain both separate AsynTask's for both classes

Answer (score 7):

Its so simple just Simply build an object of main class and than call the inner class like this

```
 OuterMainClass outer = new OuterMainClass();
       outer.new InnerAsyncClass(param)
         .execute();
```

this answer is too late to help you but hope it help others.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you will need to move the async task from being annonymus class to be a normal class, instead of being inside class A.

Make a class that extends Asynctask and have two instances of that async task both in your activities.

Comment: That's the way to go. If you need A's inner class AA inside of B, then you're doing something wrong. Just make A, B and C classes.

Answer (score 1):

Making a separate Class of `AsyncTask`. and calling it in both `activities` is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare Async Task as public static inner class in Class A. and execute it from class B.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation! Look at this answer...make on one service class to handle all your threading....perfect example here:

> Good Example on GitHub [WebServiceAsyncTask](https://github.com/jbeerdev/BrightHubCode/blob/master/src/com/bright/hub/background/WebServiceAsyncTask.java) and [WebServiceBackgroundActivity](https://github.com/jbeerdev/BrightHubCode/blob/master/src/com/bright/hub/background/WebServiceBackgroundActivity.java). VIA [Android: How to run asynctask from different class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119305/android-how-to-run-asynctask-from-different-class-file#comment7113760_6119456)