# Showing a progress bar while database is initialised

Tags: android, android-room

I'm in the progress of moving my Sqlite DB in my Android app to a Room implementation. On first setup the database needs to be populated from a CSV shipped with the apk (this can't be changed). This can take up to 30 seconds during which I display a progress bar to the user and block them from proceeding. I find this a better experience for the user then them waiting for data to appear on first query.

In my current implementation I subclass SQLiteOpenHelper, providing a Handler field that I can set before calling getReadableDatabase (which has always seemed a bit of a hack). Progress can then be returned to the calling Handler. However in Room implementation the database is initialised by a callback on the Dagger2 provided Room database. Question is how can I still show a progress dialog to the user during this setup?

**DatabaseModule**

```
 package uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.modules;


import android.app.Application;
import android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Binds;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;
import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.dao.HillDao;
import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.dao.HillTypeDao;
import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.dao.TypeLinkDao;
import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.database.BaggingTable;
import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.database.BritishHillsDatasource;
import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.database.HillsDatabase;
import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.database.HillsDatabaseHelper;
import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.database.HillsLocalDatasource;
import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.database.HillsTables;

import static android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.JournalMode.TRUNCATE;

@Module
public class DatabaseModule {



    @Provides
    @Singleton
    HillsDatabase providesRoomDatabase(Application application) {

        return Room.databaseBuilder(application, HillsDatabase.class, "hill-list.db").addMigrations(HillsDatabase.MIGRATION_2_3)
                .addCallback(new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        HillsTables.onCreate(db, application);//, handler, 9999999);
                    }
                }).setJournalMode(TRUNCATE).build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    HillDao providesHillDao(HillsDatabase database) {
        return database.hillDao();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    HillTypeDao providesHillTypeDao(HillsDatabase database) {
        return database.hillTypeDao();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    TypeLinkDao providesTypeLinkDao(HillsDatabase database) {
        return database.typeLinkDao();
    }
}
```

**HillsTables**

```
package uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.database;

import android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteStatement;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class HillsTables {

    private static final String HILLS_CSV = "DoBIH_v15.5.csv";

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String HILLS_TABLE = "hills";
    public static final String HILLTYPES_TABLE = "hilltypes";
    public static final String TYPES_LINK_TABLE = "typeslink";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_HILLNAME = "Name";
    public static final String KEY_SECTION = "Section";
    public static final String KEY_SECTIONNAME = "Section name";
    public static final String KEY_AREA = "Area";
    public static final String KEY_CLASSIFICATION = "Classification";
    public static final String KEY_MAP = "Map 1:50k";
    public static final String KEY_MAP25 = "Map 1:25k";
    public static final String KEY_HEIGHTM = "Metres";
    public static final String KEY_HEIGHTF = "Feet";
    public static final String KEY_GRIDREF = "Grid ref";
    public static final String KEY_GRIDREF10 = "Grid ref 10";
    public static final String KEY_DROP = "Drop";
    public static final String KEY_COLGRIDREF = "Col grid ref";
    public static final String KEY_COLHEIGHT = "Col height";
    public static final String KEY_FEATURE = "Feature";
    public static final String KEY_OBSERVATIONS = "Observations";
    public static final String KEY_SURVEY = "Survey";
    public static final String KEY_CLIMBED = "Climbed";
    public static final String KEY_REVISION = "Revision";
    public static final String KEY_COMMENTS = "Comments";
    public static final String KEY_STREETMAP = "Streetmap/OSiViewer";
    public static final String KEY_GEOGRAPH = "Geograph/MountainViews";
    public static final String KEY_HILLBAGGING = "Hill-bagging";
    public static final String KEY_XCOORD = "Xcoord";
    public static final String KEY_YCOORD = "Ycoord";
    public static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "Latitude";
    public static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "Longitude";
    public static final String KEY_XSECTION = "_Section";
    public static final String KEY_HILL_ID = "hill_id";
    public static final String KEY_TYPES_ID = "type_id";


    private static final String HILLTYPES_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + HILLTYPES_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key," + KEY_TITLE + " unique)";

    private static final String TYPESLINK_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TYPES_LINK_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement," + KEY_HILL_ID
            + " references " + HILLS_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + ")," + KEY_TYPES_ID
            + " references " + HILLTYPES_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + "))";
    private static Handler handler;


    public static void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database, Context context){//, Handler handler, int rows) {

        //createSimpleTables(database);
        //HillsTables.handler = handler;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();



        createAndPopulateHillsTable(database, context, startTime);//, rows);

        populateHillTypes(database, startTime);



    }

    static void populateHillTypes(SupportSQLiteDatabase database, long startTime) {

        Cursor c = database.query("select * from "+HILLS_TABLE);
        SupportSQLiteStatement insertHillType = database.compileStatement("INSERT or IGNORE into " + HILLTYPES_TABLE + " VALUES(?,?)");
        SupportSQLiteStatement insertHillTypeLink = database.compileStatement("INSERT into " + TYPES_LINK_TABLE + " (" + KEY_HILL_ID + "," + KEY_TYPES_ID + ") values (?,?)");

        // Populate static hill types data
        database.beginTransaction();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String[] classifications = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CLASSIFICATION)).replace("\"", "").split(",");
                for (String classification : classifications) {
                    insertHillType.bindString(2, classification);
                    insertHillType.bindLong(1, c.getColumnIndex(classification));
                    insertHillType.executeInsert();

                    insertHillTypeLink.bindLong(1, c.getInt(0));
                    insertHillTypeLink.bindLong(2, c.getColumnIndex(classification));
                    insertHillTypeLink.executeInsert();
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        database.endTransaction();
        c.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "populateHillTypes: Finished inserting hill types information after "
                        + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000);
    }

    private static void createAndPopulateHillsTable(SupportSQLiteDatabase database, Context context, long startTime){//, int rows) {
        InputStream is;
        Log.d(TAG, "createAndPopulateHillsTable: starting");
        try {

            is = context.getAssets().open(HILLS_CSV);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is));

            //createHillsTable(database, reader);
            String headerRow = reader.readLine();

            StringBuffer insertHillsBuffer;


            // read main hill data into hills table
            database.beginTransaction();
            String line;
            int count = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && count <= 23000) {
                count++;
                if(handler != null) {
                    handler.dispatchMessage(Message.obtain(handler, 0, 0, 1, 1));
                }

                insertHillsBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                insertHillsBuffer.append("INSERT INTO " + HILLS_TABLE
                        + " VALUES (");
                String[] lineArray = line
                        .split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

                for (String entry : lineArray) {
                    insertHillsBuffer.append("'").append(entry.replace("'", "''")).append("',");
                }
                insertHillsBuffer.deleteCharAt(insertHillsBuffer.length() - 1);

                insertHillsBuffer.append(")");
                database.execSQL(insertHillsBuffer.toString());
            }

            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
            database.endTransaction();
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "#################Finished inserting base hill information after "
                            + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,
                    "Failed to populate hills database table", e);
        }
    }

    private static void createHillsTable(SupportSQLiteDatabase database, BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
        String headerRow = reader.readLine();
        String hillsTableStarter = "CREATE TABLE '" + HILLS_TABLE
                + "' ('" + KEY_ID + "' integer primary key,";
        String[] headerArray = headerRow.split(",");
        StringBuilder createHillsTableBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String header : headerArray) {
            header = header.replace("\uFEFF","");
            if (!"Number".equals(header)) {
                createHillsTableBuilder.append("'").append(header).append("',");
            }
        }
        String c = createHillsTableBuilder.toString();
        database.execSQL(hillsTableStarter + c.substring(0, c.length() - 1) + ")");
    }

    private static void createSimpleTables(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        database.execSQL(HILLTYPES_CREATE);
        database.execSQL(TYPESLINK_CREATE);
    }

    public static void onUpgrade(SupportSQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
                                 int newVersion, Context context, Handler handler, int rows) {
        Log.w(HillsTables.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
                + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                + ", which will destroy all old hills data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + HILLS_TABLE);
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + HILLTYPES_TABLE);
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TYPES_LINK_TABLE);
        //onCreate(database, context, handler, rows);
    }

}
```

**SplashScreenActivity**

```
package uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.activities;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.widget.TextView;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.BHApplication;
import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.R;
import uk.colessoft.android.hilllist.database.BritishHillsDatasource;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0x00001;
    public static final int MAX = 20782;
    private Thread splashThread;
    private Handler handler;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Inject
    BritishHillsDatasource dbAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((BHApplication) getApplication()).getDbComponent().inject(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        TextView link=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
        Linkify.addLinks(link, Linkify.ALL);

        handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if(msg.arg1 == 0)
                    progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                else {
                    SplashScreenActivity.this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER);
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                }
            }
        };

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SplashScreenActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Updating Database");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMax(MAX);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();


        splashThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {


                SplashScreenActivity.this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);


                dbAdapter.touch(handler);
                handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, 0, 1, 1, 1));

                try {

                    int waited = 0;

                    while (waited < 1800) {

                        sleep(100);

                        waited += 100;

                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    // do nothing

                } finally {

                    finish();
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,

                            Main.class);

                    startActivity(i);

                }

            }

        };

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to the SD Card to read and write the Database",
                        (dialog, which) -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            }
        }else {
            splashThread.start();

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    splashThread.start();


                } else {
                    finish();
                }

            }

        }
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreenActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

}
```

Comment: "On first setup the database needs to be populated from a CSV shipped with the apk (this can't be changed)" -- if it is possible to put a CSV in the APK, it is possible to change that to put a SQLite database in the APK. For example, as part of building the APK, your development machine (or build server or whatever) could run a script to take the CSV and generate the SQLite database.

Comment: @CommonsWare would this "solve" the problem?  Would it really make it 100 times faster to "import" a existing db like https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/packing-the-room-pre-populate-your-database-with-this-one-method-333ae190e680. and is it worth the effort and dev time - what are the advantages if it's a simple csv? if it had complex relationships, sure, but for simple csv.. especially if team is used to updating CSV, then you have to create a "process"

Comment: @nAndroid: "and is it worth the effort and dev time" -- you are going to need code to convert CSV into SQL statements and execute them. Your choices are doing that at compile time or at runtime. Your "effort and dev time" will exist in either case. From the user's perspective, compile time is preferable, as it is faster.

Comment: @CommonsWare I didn't mention it was a refactor and the runtime conversion already existed :). I ended up taking this suggestion - and i appreciate it and i'm pretty happy with it except I'm concerned it might be out of the next guy's wheelhouse, and/or that i didn't include good enough instructions. In particular the import chopping off the leading zeroes even when i say "don't autodetect data type" with sql lite browser.

Answer (score -1):

Try use `ProgressBar` with `AsyncTask`. Here are the helpful links:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15487920/9626373
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963705/9626373