# Download from internet with custom buffer and detect percentage of download

Tags: android

I use this code to download form internet. I want to show progress of download! To do this I need to know what amount of data has been received and ...
But How should I do it?

I mean I should have buffer so that data is read into the buffer and from buffer it is put in output! and do this in Loop!

```
dest_File=new File(dest_FilePath);
                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest_File));

                url=new URL(URL);
                urlConnection=url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                contenLength=urlConnection.getContentLength();
                inputStream=new DataInputStream(url.openStream());
                buffer=new byte[contenLength];
                progress.setMax(contenLength);


             publishProgress((int) (total ));
             outputStream.write(buffer);

            inputStream.close();

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following link [Android: How to run asynctask from different class file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119305/android-how-to-run-asynctask-from-different-class-file) it uses DownloadFileAsync.java class for download try this may help you