# How can I display an AlertDialog from a Class not extending Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I want to show an Alert Dialog when a user enters a wrong email or password.
The problem is that the class doesn't extend Activity and also the AlertDialog should be in the `onPostExecute()` of an `Asynctask`

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.akshay.registerandlogin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 30-07-2015.
 */
public class ServerWork {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ProgressDialog pg;
    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://www.funvilla.in/test/Register.php";
    private static String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.funvilla.in/test/Login.php";
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
    String username,password;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader br;
    StringBuilder sb;
    UserData user;

    public ServerWork()
    {

    }
    public void RegisterData(Context context) {
       /* progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);*/

        new StoreData().execute();
    }

    public void GetDataFromServer(Context context) {
        /*pg = new ProgressDialog(context);*/

        new getData(context).execute();
    }

    public class StoreData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
         /*   progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Establishing Connection");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait......");
            progressDialog.show();
*/
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.e("CHECCCCKKKK" ,user.NAME );
            Log.e("CHECCCCKKKK" ,user.EMAIL );
            Log.e("CHECCCCKKKK" ,user.USERNAME );
            Log.e("CHECCCCKKKK" ,user.PASSWORD );

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSave = new ArrayList<>();
           dataToSave.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.NAME));
            dataToSave.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.EMAIL));
            dataToSave.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", String.valueOf(user.AGE)));
            dataToSave.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.USERNAME));
            dataToSave.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.PASSWORD));
            dataToSave.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", user.DATE));
            dataToSave.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", user.TIME));

            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(REGISTER_URL);

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSave));
                httpClient.execute(post);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.e("HttpClient", "Problem near Line 70 ServerWork.java");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
          /*  progressDialog.dismiss();*/

        }


    }

    public class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
Context context;
        public getData(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {


            super.onPreExecute();
           /* pg.setCancelable(false);
            pg.setTitle("Please Wait");
            pg.setMessage("Establishing Connection");
            pg.show();*/
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> login = new ArrayList<>();
            login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.USERNAME));
            login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.PASSWORD));
            HttpParams httpparams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpparams, TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpparams, TIMEOUT);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpparams);
            String encodedURl = URLEncodedUtils.format(login, "utf-8");
            LOGIN_URL += "?" + encodedURl;
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(LOGIN_URL);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String line = null;
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("check", sb.toString());
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                String name = object.getString("name");
                String email = object.getString("email");
                int age = object.getInt("age");
                username = object.getString("username");
                password = object.getString("password");
                Log.e("check", name);
                Log.e("check", email);
                Log.e("check", String.valueOf(age));
                Log.e("check", username);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            /*pg.dismiss();*/

            if((UserData.USERNAME).equals(username) && UserData.PASSWORD.equals(password))
            {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context,MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
            }
            else
            {

               AlertDialog.Builder m = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                m.setMessage("Wrong pass");
                m.show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119305/android-how-to-run-asynctask-from-different-class-file or you can use [an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517400/inner-class-can-access-but-not-update-values-asynctask/18517648#18517648)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by various component like Interfaces or Broadcast Receivers but I would suggest to use [Otto]: http://square.github.io/otto/ as it is quite simple to use and also your code readability will be increase. You will find a running example here :- http://www.cardinalsolutions.com/blog/2015/02/event-bus-on-android

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the activity and context  to other class that is not extending class like

Example

```
Method(Context context , Activity activity)
{
startActivity( new intent(this , alertDialogClass.class)
}
```

In the alertDialogClass use the context and activity to show alert dialogbox