# Making A Toast In An Activity From Different Java Class File

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 2 `.java` files : `AnswerActivity.java`

```
public class AnswerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);

        new JSONTask().execute("https://example.com/api.php");
    }
}
```

and `JSONTask.java`

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    //--- some code cut here ---//

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, AnswerActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(i, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

my last 2 lines always gives me error :

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AnswerActivity.class);
    Toast.makeText(i, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I want to display the `result` into AnswerActivity as a Toast. but why I always get this error message?

```
Error:(68, 20) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(JSONTask,Class<AnswerActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; JSONTask cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; JSONTask cannot be converted to Context)

Error:(69, 14) error: no suitable method found for makeText(Intent,String,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Intent cannot be converted to Context)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Intent cannot be converted to Context)
```

what did I miss here? thank you

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4823947/4350275 . You need something like this.

Comment: I would advise you not to do any UI stuff from your AsyncTask. Pass in a JobDoneListener interface or something and call back to your activity when it's completed, then call the Toast there. That way you can do whatever UI manipulation you want after the AsyncTask is completed (not just a Toast).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a context to show a `Toast`. Usually it's the `Activity` or the `Fragment` having the context. But since your `AsyncTask` is not a inner class of your `AnswerActivity` you have no reference to a context.
So you could pass the `Activity` in the constructor and use that

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private Context context;

    public JSONTask(Context context){
      this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And use it with

```
new JSONTask(this)... // and so on
```

The big advantage of this is, that you do not keep a reference to the `Activity` and just pass the `Context` - since Activity does extend the Context.

Comment: Beware with this. If your JSONTask can live longer than the lifecycle of the Activity (for example if you have a slow connection and you close the app) this will cause a memory leak. https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Answer (score 2):

Remove this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AnswerActivity.class);
    Toast.makeText(i, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

With this:

Pass `Context` in `AsyncTask` class:

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private Context context;
//in constructor:
public JSONTask(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

//--- some code cut here ---//

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);


    Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

And use this in `Activity`:

```
new JSONTask(AnswerActivity.this).execute("https://example.com/api.php");
```

Comment: hi bro, I got this message in result : Error:(68, 38) error: not an enclosing class: AnswerActivity

Comment: @RobertHanson, is this asynctask is a inside class or external class?

Comment: if error persist, make a `Constructor` to pass the context.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSONTask should be

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context mContext;

    public JSONTask(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //--- some code cut here ---//
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Initialization

```
 new JSONTask(this).execute("https://example.com/api.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using `JSONTask` class anywhere else then you can define it within your `AnswerActivity` as an [inner class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_innerclasses.htm). If you do that then this code should work,

```
Toast.makeText(AnswerActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Otherwise you have to pass your application context to the `JSONTask` and use that within `Toast`.

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private Context appContext;

    public JSONTask(Context context){
        this.appContext= context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    //--- some code cut here ---//

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);    
        Toast.makeText(appContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is create a constructor in the class

```
Context context;

public void init(Context ctx){
       this.context = ctx;
}
```

Then you can create the Toast

```
Toast.makeText(this.context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Seriously, a static reference to an activity?