# Is it safe to keep a reference to a ContentResolver in an AsyncTask without leaking memory?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask, android-contentresolver

I have an AsyncTask in which I'm running a database query. For this purpose my AsyncTask subclass contains a field of the type ContentResolver. I'm wondering if it's safe to have it or if it will cause memory leaks like in the case of a Context ([AsyncTask and Contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912725/asynctask-and-contexts))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/16dd960/core/java/android/content/ContentResolver.java#785) I could see that ContentResolver keeps a reference to the Context which created it (I guess), so you should take care of it like with any Context references.

But anw you can always use a ContentResolver from the ApplicationContext, it's [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987503/1562087) to be safe to use.

Edit: Or maybe you don't need to store a ContentResolver at all. You can always create one from an existing Context by [this constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#ContentResolver(android.content.Context)). (That constructor even doesn't need a Context, just pass `null` and it will automatically use the ApplicationContext)